# Elements of a subgroup and explanation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Find all of the elements in the subgroup K = $\langle (12)(34),(125)\rangle \leq S_5$.
I understand that you need to take the powers of the given elements and products, but I don't understand how for example $\beta^2=(125)(125)=(152)$. Where do you get $(152)$ from?

Comment: Your question should be entitled 'How do I multiply permutations?'

Comment: Do you understand what the notation $(1 \space 5 \space 2)$ signifies?

Comment: I do not, also is there a way for me to edit the title. Sorry - I am new to posting here.

Comment: They are permutations. ${S_n}$ refers to the "Symmetric Group"

Comment: You can find more information about this group here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1 \space 2 \space 5)$ signifies the permutation that sends $1$ to $2$, sends $2$ to $5$, sends $5$ to $1$, and fixes all other elements.

We understand $(1 \space 5 \space 2)$ in a similar way.

Both of these permuataations are examples of *cycles* because they consist of precisely one cycle involving some of the numbers, and leave the rest of the numbers fixed.

Any permutation in $S_5$ (or any $S_n$) can be written as a product of **disjoint** (i.e., non-overlapping) cycles. So we want to figure out how to write the permutation
$$
(1 \space 2 \space 5)(1 \space 2 \space 5)
$$
in this way. Remember to read from right to left. What happens to $1$? Starting from the right, $1$ is sent to $2$ by the righthand copy of $(1 \space 2 \space 5)$. Then $2$ is sent to $5$ in the lefthand copy of $(1 \space 2 \space 5)$. So, altogether, moving through both copies, $1$ is sent to $5$. Now we want to continue making a cycle and ask what happens to $5$. If you follow the same steps you'll find that $5$ is sent to $2$. Then ask what happens to $2$ and you'll see it is sent to $1$. So this gives us the cycle $(1 \space 5 \space 2)$.

To conclude that this is the *only* cycle we need in the product, we just have to observe that the rest of the numbers ($3$ and $4$) are fixed by $(1 \space 2 \space 5)(1 \space 2 \space 5)$. So there are no more cycles in the product.

Comment: Very descriptive answer and also explains to OP what is meant by the cycle notation! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

$(152)$ refers to a permutation on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$ Said another way, it is a function $$\sigma : \{1,2,3,4,5\} \longrightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5\}$$ which is a bijection and whose behavior on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is $$\sigma(1) = 5$$ $$\sigma(2) = 1$$ $$\sigma(3) = 3$$ $$\sigma(4) = 4$$ $$\sigma(5)= 2.$$ The group operation is function composition and so $(152)(152)$ is the function $\sigma \circ \sigma$. I leave it to you to see that $(152)^2 = (125).$

Comment: I like this answer too! Very short, sweet and concise

Answer (score 0):

Since $(125)$ is a $3$-cycle, its square is its inverse; hence

$$(125)^2=(521)=(152),$$

by the fact that the inverse of a cycle is the cycle whose elements are in the reverse order of that cycle.